# Developing with a Split Frontend/Backend MS Access Database from the start

Tags: ms-access

I am starting to create an MSAccess database, I have no Access experience - my previous experience is with MySQL and Oracle. Initially I had some difficulty coming to terms with the fact that MSAccess usually stores both the front end application and the Jet Engine database in the same file. It's different from what I'm used to. Plus the database will be shared over a network, and it just makes more sense to split the application from the data.

After some reading, I see that it is possible to store data in one file, and then link to the application elements in another file. Every article I've come across for this deals with *splitting* the database into two parts, after the database has already been made, and never discusses creating split database applications from the start. Is it because that would be a bad idea? I can't really imagine why, except that I've noticed that Access does not let me keep two database files open at the same time (it automatically closes one). So I am foreseeing a need to constantly to open and re-open files if I go down that route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one practical reason why you might want to start with a single database. If you start with a front and back end file, you'll have to create tables in one database, then set up the link for each table manually.

This is not a big deal, but if you're just starting the system, you can save some busywork by developing the pilot system in one file, then splitting it. My assumption is you'll probably be making a lot of changes to the data structure at the outset; your work will go smoother if you're working in one file.

It is definitely a good idea to split the database before you deploy it to production. I'm not sure why you're having problems opening 2 Access files at once; this is not a restriction of Access.

Comment: You do not have to refresh the link when you are working with Jet/ACE. Furthermore, I have found there are less problems with development and decompiling when you have an early split.

Comment: I didn't realize this, but I see from a quick test that design changes do propagate from the back end with JET (usually my back-ends are SQL Server).

Comment: So I should be ok with having a split database from the onset, if design changes propagate right? I've already spent 2 weeks just gathering requirements and drawing ERDs on paper, but yeah, there still probably will be design changes.

Comment: You will absolutely be OK. I consider this a matter of personal preference and development style.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the two db files separately at the outset.  I do that often.  I seldom need both open at the same time in the Access interface.  I only open the back-end database, which houses the tables, indexes, and relationships, to modify the design of those db objects.  And those types of changes are relatively infrequent; most of the development workload is for the front-end db.  To modify **data** in the tables, you can use the table links from the front-end db.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bad idea. You can have two files open at the same time, either open another Access instance or launch by double-clicking the second file. Make sure you have created a suitable back-end design before you start on the front-end.

Answer (score 2):

It is more efficient to have it all in one file while you're alone to work on it. Once the database design is finalised, then you can split the db.
Splitting the db is usefull during testing as well: it allows you to reset your data to a known state in about 5 sec, just by copying a saved version of the back-end.